# Geometric induction of modules for algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, induced-representations

Let $\Bbbk$ be an algebraically closed field (of any characteristic).  Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $\Bbbk$, and $H$ a closed (hence algebraic) subgroup of $G$.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $H$-module.  Then we define $\operatorname{Ind}^{G}_HV$ to be $(\Bbbk[G]\otimes V)^H$, where $H$ acts on $\Bbbk[G]$ via right translation. With this definition, $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}V$ is naturally a module over the commutative algebra $\Bbbk[G]^H$.

We know that $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}V$ is the global sections of a vector bundle on $G/H$.  However, if $G/H$ is not affine, then a priori $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}V$ may not be a projective module over $\Bbbk[G]^H$; however I don't know any examples.

Thus my question: is $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}V$ always a finitely generated, projective module over $\Bbbk[G]^H$?

Comment: I believe the following works.  Let $n>1$ be an integer.  Let $G$ be $\textbf{GL}_n$.  Let $H$ be the intersection of $\textbf{SL}_n$ with a maximal parabolic $P\leq \textbf{GL}_n$ whose quotient is $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.  So $k[G]^H$ should be the coordinate $k$-algebra of affine $n$-space.  Now let $V$ be the quotient of the Lie algebras $\mathfrak{gl}_n/\mathfrak{p}$.  This corresponds to the tangent bundle on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ whose module is not flat over $k[G]^H$.

Comment: Actually, we need $n>2$ for that to work.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!